# Crash on iOS: com.apple.main-thread | EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, combine

Crashes are reported into firebase console, and it's happening very rarely without any concrete repro steps. Below is my crash log:

Any Idea why would this happen?

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000104f9d960
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: SIGNAL 5 Trace/BPT trap: 5
Terminating Process: exc handler \[9693\]

Triggered by Thread:  0

Kernel Triage:
VM - pmap_enter failed with resource shortage
VM - pmap_enter failed with resource shortage
VM - pmap_enter failed with resource shortage

Thread 0 name:   Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   MyApp                                  0x104f9d960 0x104940000 + 6674784
1   MyApp                                  0x104f9ca0c 0x104940000 + 6670860
2   Combine                                0x1bf1e34b0 Subscribers.Sink.receive(_:) + 96
3   Combine                                0x1bf1e2da8 protocol witness for Subscriber.receive(_:) in conformance Subscribers.Sink\<A, B\> + 24
4   Combine                                0x1bf1ea9fc closure #1 in Publishers.ReceiveOn.Inner.receive(\_:) + 288
5   libswiftDispatch.dylib                 0x1c0cddc04 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -\> () + 36
6   libdispatch.dylib                      0x1a6d9ae6c \_dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
7   libdispatch.dylib                      0x1a6d9ca30 \_dispatch_client_callout + 20
8   libdispatch.dylib                      0x1a6daaf48 \_dispatch_main_queue_drain + 928
9   libdispatch.dylib                      0x1a6daab98 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 44
10  CoreFoundation                         0x1a70ed800 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 16
11  CoreFoundation                         0x1a70a7704 \__CFRunLoopRun + 2532
12  CoreFoundation                         0x1a70babc8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600
13  GraphicsServices                       0x1c3226374 GSEventRunModal + 164
14  UIKitCore                              0x1a9a2eb58 -\[UIApplication run\] + 1100
15  UIKitCore                              0x1a97b0090 UIApplicationMain + 364
16  SwiftUI                                0x1aef14f24 closure #1 in KitRendererCommon(_:) + 164
17  SwiftUI                                0x1aee42e08 runApp\<A\>(:) + 252
18  SwiftUI                                0x1aee240f4 static App.main() + 128
19  MyApp                                  0x104944840 0x104940000 + 18496
20  dyld                                   0x105d7dda4 start + 520
```

Tried symbolicating the crash using the dysm file too, yet unable to get to the root cause.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: According to the stack trace the crash occurs nearby `sink`ing a Combine pipeline.

Comment: Look at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/addressing-crashes-from-swift-runtime-errors.  The `EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)` suggests it might be the swift runtime that's killed the app.  Often this comes from force-unwrapping an optional that's nil, or using something like `preconditionFailure`

Comment: Frames 0 and 1 indicate that something happens in response to `Subscribers.Sink.receive`. Check that code for force unwrap, array boundaries, type conversion compatibility - basically anything that can cause a specific piece of "memory" not to contain something Swift runtime thinks it should contain

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help guys. I think I was able to figure out the issue & it was happening due to `array boundaries` scenario. Appreciate your help and prompt response.